# Find angle between Two Position

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager, angle

I have Latitude and Longitude of two position.

I already find out distance between this two position.

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[player.strLatitude floatValue] longitude:[player.strLongitude floatValue]];
CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:app.lat longitude:app.lag];
CLLocationDistance distance = [locB distanceFromLocation:locA];
NSLog(@"Distance%f",distance);
[locA release]; [locB release];
```

Now i want to find out angle between this two position.

In center there is one user position and i want to display other user location in that Cicle at apporipate angle.

Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: Are you just looking for the atan2f function?

Comment: Sorry i dont know about atan2f function. Can you please provide some Link?

Comment: have you skipped the elementary maths classes...?

Comment: @holex I know the meaning of atan but i dont know how can i use it to find angle between two CLLocation!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: it is basic trigonometry only. someone has mentioned the `tan`, but I think for that solution the laws of `cos` can be implemented easier here, **[check the formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help you

```
- (CGFloat)angleBetweenLinesInRadians:(CGPoint)line1Start 
                         line1End:(CGPoint)line1End 
                       line2Start:(CGPoint)line2Start 
                         line2End:(CGPoint)line2End 
{
CGFloat a = line1End.x - line1Start.x;
CGFloat b = line1End.y - line1Start.y;
CGFloat c = line2End.x - line2Start.x;
CGFloat d = line2End.y - line2Start.y;

CGFloat line1Slope = (line1End.y - line1Start.y) / (line1End.x - line1Start.x);
CGFloat line2Slope = (line2End.y - line2Start.y) / (line2End.x - line2Start.x);

CGFloat degs = acosf(((a*c) + (b*d)) / ((sqrt(a*a + b*b)) * (sqrt(c*c + d*d))));


return (line2Slope > line1Slope) ? degs : -degs;
```

}

Comment: I dont have 4 points as your Function suggests. I have two Positions.(Longitude and Latitude)